# Getting an error ....'RptFeedback_ItemID_0' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have reviewed the other questions similar to this, but have not found a solution. I'm sure I am simply missing something, but I do have the form runat= server, so not sure why it is throwing this error. I also have all the textbox's set to runat "server". I am attempting to have a button that exports data to excel after the form is populated. This is asp with c# behind:

aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FeedBackForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="FeedBackForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Portion ID"></asp:Label>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="portionIDTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearchFeedback" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearchFeedback_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />

         <asp:Repeater ID="RptFeedback" runat="server">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Item ID
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Item DB Key
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Candidate ID
                                    </th>    
                                    <th>Date
                                    </th>   
                                    <th>Feedback
                                    </th>                                                                    
                                </tr>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="ItemID"  runat="server" Width ="100px" Text='<%#Eval("Item ID") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="ItemDBKey"  runat="server" Width ="90px" Text='<%#Eval("Item DB Key") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="CandidateID" runat="server" Width ="100px" Text='<%#Eval("Candidate ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>    
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Date" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>  
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Feedback" runat="server" Width ="600px" Text='<%#Eval("Feedback") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>                        
                               </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            </table>
                        </FooterTemplate>                    
                    </asp:Repeater>
            <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export" OnClick = "ExportToExcel" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

cs for export btn:

```
 protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
        "attachment;filename=RepeaterExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        RptFeedback.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

and the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Control 'RptFeedback_ItemID_0' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Control 'RptFeedback_ItemID_0' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Source Error: 



Line 40:         StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
Line 41:         HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
Line 42:         RptFeedback.RenderControl(hw);
Line 43:         Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Line 44:         Response.Flush();
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension. And as you have seen your technique creates additional problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling RptFeedback.RenderControl(hw), this raises an exception that a Server-Control was rendered outside of a Form.

You can avoid this by overriding

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
   /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
 server control at run time. */
}
```

Comment: I had to add EnableEventValidation="false" for this to generate an excel doc. The Text doesn't sit inside of excel cells, but it does put them in there in some odd way. Thank you.